# Django - MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

Could you please suggest me the good documentation where I can understand the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT? It's really confusing me.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303254/what-does-django-do-with-media-root

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `MEDIA_ROOT` is the path *on the filesystem* to the directory containing your static media.

The `MEDIA_URL` is the URL that makes the static media accessible over HTTP.

The docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#media-root

The main idea is that serving things through python+django is expensive.  Since your media is static you don't need to pay that cost, so you serve it differently (e.g. directly via nginx or through a CDN). However, you still need to know where the media is located in the file system (e.g. for file uploads) and what the URL is (e.g. to put in templates). The settings exist to tie all that together.

Comment: The only thing left to add to this is that you then use `MEDIA_URL` to reference files via their URLs and `MEDIA_ROOT` to reference them physically, i.e. displaying an image in HTML `MEDIA_URLimages/myimage.png` translates to `http://myapp/media/images/myimage.png`; opening an image to resize it `os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'images/myimage.png')` translates to `/path/to/myapp/media/images/myimage.png`

Comment: a question, should I commit the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory