# how to save csv file in static folder in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to save a csv file in django static folder. I tried creating a file  named 'data.csv' in my app, but the file is saved in base directory. Where and how can I most easily save a csv file in django?

```
file=open('data.csv','w')
header='product_name,Price,seller\n'
file.write(header)
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify the static folder during run; it's meant to be static. Instead use the media folder (as described by @JerinPeterGeorge below).

Comment: @AKX, thanks so much for mentioning this! I wanted to do the same thing as OP, not aware that the **static** folder is meant to be *static*, :-)

Answer (score 2):

set the **`MEDIA_ROOT`** in your `settings.py` and open file as

```
from django.conf import settings

file_name = "{}data.csv".format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
file = open(file_name, 'w')
```

Comment: The file is save in the base directory not in static or media

Comment: I don't understand you. Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: when i try this code the csv file is saved in the base directory.not in the media folder.

Comment: What is the value of `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` ?

Comment: No man. Go to Django shell and try my answer by pasting one by one. You will get the right output

Comment: the value is 'data.csv'

Comment: What's the output of **`print(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`**?

Comment: its null.there is no value.

Comment: but when i try this  file=open(settings.STATIC_ROOT+'data.csv','w')  i got this value <open file '/home/guest/Documents/Djangoproject/scrapper/data.csv', mode 'w' at 0x7fde67507300>

Comment: You have to set **`MEDIA_ROOT='media/'`** in `settings.py` file where `media` is the directory in project base

Comment: The logic is you should provide a **absolute path** while open the file

Comment: yes it is stored in the media . but i need to access that file.

Comment: What's problem now?

Comment: i need to access the data.csv in my html page. im usually using     <a href="{% static 'data.csv' %}">data</a>

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820122/django-media-root-and-media-url