# Django media URL serving behind the scene through

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I understand the difference between `MEDAI_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` that root is used for upload and URL is used to access it through HTTP but there's one thing that I don't understand as per this answer
[Django - MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820122/django-media-root-and-media-url)
the webserver e.g Nginx handles the static files, not python but how does the webserver know the path to the images without python even though that it only sees the e.g `127.0.0.1/images/product11.png` and the images actually stores in the path `127.0.0.1/static/images/product1.png`

Comment: In the configuration file for nginx, you specify where nginx needs to look for the static file and at what URL it has to serve it.

Comment: yes but in the setting si only set the media URL to only `/images/ ` and didn't specify the whole  path how  does the Nginx know the path

Comment: nginx knows the path from the nginx configuration file not from the Django settings file.

Comment: ok, let's consider locally how when using media url and navigate through `127.0.0.1/images/product1.png`  how does the server know the physical location of the images even though in the `MEDIA_URL` I only defined the `images/

Comment: MEDIA_URL is for generating the static URL and MEDIA_ROOT is the absolute path to the directory where media files are being stored. That is answered already in the question you shared, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820924/11566173)

Comment: yeah I know that the question is in the media root I provide the complete path to the file but in the media URL I only provide the directory name how does  it know that media url will be redirected to the media root absolute path

Comment: Eg: https://localhost:8000/media/photos/myphoto.jpg, this will display the picture stored at myprojectdir/media/photos/myphoto.jpg
Now Django will use the location from the URL and use the MEDIA_ROOT to find the image in the project directory. Please note that this happens only in the development server, in production nginx handles this.

Comment: Aha ok got thank you for you answer