# django MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django

if i am setting up apache (PRODUCTION) to serve static files(js,css,jpg,pdf,mp4),should i set the variable `MEDIA_ROOT` in settings.py.

I mean anyways any thing matching `/media/` will be served by apache not django.So what exactly is then the use of `MEDIA_ROOT`.In such an enviornment is there any purpose of `MEDIA_URL` except as a shortcut to `/media/`.Similarly whats the purpose of `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` other than as a shortcut.

Comment: i got the answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303254/what-does-django-do-with-media-root]. Its becoming difficult to search inside stackoverflow these days.search algorith has to be updated i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303254/what-does-django-do-with-media-root%5D%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B)

I got the answer to my question(as mentioned in my comment).I is was reviewing my stalkoverflow profile and I saw this question unanswered and unclosed.So have pasted the link as an answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you need to tell Django where to the browser can find those files that are being served by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

difference is MEDIA_ROOT indicates where you should put your static files, and MEDIA_URL is the relative path where those are being served.

in a production environement, MEDIA_* paths are (commonly, but it's not strict to follow) used to store application related static files (css, imgs and javascripts). For user uploaded content, it's good practice (but again, it's not a rule) to save them inside the STATIC path, so you can move/delete/dostuff with them without compromising your app

so basically, to answer your question (didn't see any question mark in your post, btw) MEDIA_ROOT is the absolute path on the server where the static files have to be stored.

[Here you can find something about MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root)

[Here something about static files management with django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: my question is in a production enviornment even if we don't set MEDIA_* in setting.py, it will work.Because static files is served by apache.Any link to a static file like /media/my.js will be served by apache. so no need to set MEDIA_*.